# Glassfish 4 - clustered setup - database connection pool on DAS

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4

I have a glassfish 4 installation (DAS). One remote (SSH) node and one cluster with one instance on that node.
Also i have defined a connection pool and the datasource for it.

My test application is very simple - it is a web application with one servlet, in that i load the datasource in the following way:

```
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/vadsacRootSource")
private Datasource datasource;
```

What does not work - the datasource on the cluster instance (remote) cannot be instantiated, because the underlying pool cannot be found - stacktrace see at the end of the message.

What does work:

- The same application on the local DAS node (defaul node)
- The Loading of a string saved as custom JNDI resource on both - remote and local
- The whole application (the datasource, too) on the glassfish 3.1 - remote and local

So, there is something wrong with the current glassfish 4 version - Datasources (or its pool) does not get instantiated (or found per JNDI?) on some remote SSH instance.
I have tested the official release 4.0 and the nightly build version 4.1-bl3 - the same problem

**Do you have any idea?**

> GlassFish Server
>   Open Source Edition  4.0  - Error report
>
> ## HTTP
>   Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> ---
>
> **type** Exception
>   report
>
> **message**Internal Server
>   Error
>
> **description**The server encountered an internal error
>   that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> **exception**
>
> ```
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class
> com.sedo.webtesty.HelloWorld
> ```
>
> **root cause**
>
> ```
> com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException:
> Error creating managed object for class: class
> com.sedo.webtesty.HelloWorld
> ```
>
> **root cause**
>
> ```
> com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException:
> Exception attempting to inject Res-Ref-Env-Property:
> com.sedo.webtesty.HelloWorld/datasource@javax.sql.DataSource@ resolved
> as: jndi: jdbc/vadsacRootSource@res principal: null@mail: null No
> Runtime properties Database Vendor : null Create Tables at Deploy :
> false Delete Tables at Undeploy : false into class
> com.sedo.webtesty.HelloWorld: Lookup failed for
> 'java:comp/env/com.sedo.webtesty.HelloWorld/datasource' in
> SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
> java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
> java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
> ```
>
> **root
>   cause**
>
> ```
> javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for
> 'java:comp/env/com.sedo.webtesty.HelloWorld/datasource' in
> SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
> java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
> java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root
> exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for
> 'jdbc/vadsacRootSource' in
> SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
> java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
> java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
> com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/com.sedo.webtesty.HelloWorld/datasource}
> [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to lookup
> resource : jdbc/vadsacRootSource [Root exception is
> com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException:
> Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/mysqlRootVadsacPool' in
> SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
> java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
> java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
> com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/com.sedo.webtesty.HelloWorld/datasource}]]]
> ```
>
> **root
>   cause**
>
> ```
> javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for
> 'jdbc/vadsacRootSource' in
> SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
> java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
> java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
> com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/com.sedo.webtesty.HelloWorld/datasource}
> [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to lookup
> resource : jdbc/vadsacRootSource [Root exception is
> com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException:
> Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/mysqlRootVadsacPool' in
> SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
> java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
> java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
> com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/com.sedo.webtesty.HelloWorld/datasource}]]
> ```
>
> **root
>   cause**
>
> ```
> javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to lookup resource
> : jdbc/vadsacRootSource [Root exception is
> com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException:
> Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/mysqlRootVadsacPool' in
> SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
> java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
> java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
> com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/com.sedo.webtesty.HelloWorld/datasource}]
> ```
>
> **root
>   cause**
>
> ```
> com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException:
> Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/mysqlRootVadsacPool' in
> SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
> java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
> java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
> com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/com.sedo.webtesty.HelloWorld/datasource}
> ```
>
> **root
>   cause**
>
> ```
> javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for
> '__SYSTEM/pools/mysqlRootVadsacPool' in
> SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
> java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
> java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
> com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/com.sedo.webtesty.HelloWorld/datasource}
> [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
> pools]
> ```
>
> **root cause**
>
> ```
> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pools
> ```
>
> **note**
>   The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
>   available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0 
>   logs.
>
> ---
>
> #### GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0

Comment: The same problem with the current development version Glassfish 4.1-bl3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed in the current 4.1 version - everything is working now